# Exporting Kibana dashboard to Report

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, kibana

I want to export a dashboard in `kibana` as a report.

I looked for a solution but all I found was that as a client side, `kibana` is not able to do that and if I interact with `elasticsearch`, Im lacking the charts and graphical design the `kibana` is capable of.

Any solutions? Anyone?

P.s: generating a report via `c#` or some other server side language is also acceptable

Comment: Apparently, such a functionality has been built into the latest version (4.6.0 at the time of writing), see https://www.elastic.co/de/products/reporting . I havn't tried it yet but it looks like it could be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now this is possible to export result in Kibana.

1. create 'visualization'
2. create 'Dashboard' using created visualizations.
3. Then we can save or share the dashboard. In share we will get this report as iFrame. We can add this in one html file.

Answer (score 1):

Eventually, no snappy result was found so I had to mix between Selenium & screencapturing.

Thanks to all of those who tried to help!

Comment: The only other option that is possible is generating an adapter between the elastic's JS and word charts and thing like that but no one is going to do such a thing....

Answer (score 0):

I belive you cannot export the Kibana results. Kibana itself just query ES and display results using JavaScript. Can't you just send a URL to a created kibana view? So your report will be a new generated view?

You can query ES directly, get the values and create your report on server side. For this you can use Java API - http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/index.html, PHP API http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/current/index.html, ...

Comment: That I already know. The question is do you know of an integrated/ open source complete solution. I am currently trying to develop a c# solution that writes the results into a word document